# How to save and read XML File from webserver in ios?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, ipad

I am using webservice first time.

I got an XML from webservice on run time.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<driver>
<full_name><![CDATA[Test Driver Name]]></full_name>
<d_o_b><![CDATA[1950-05-12]]></d_o_b>
<p_o_b><![CDATA[Test City]]></p_o_b>
<height><![CDATA[Test City]]></height>
<nationality><![CDATA[Test nationality]]></nationality>
<c_team><![CDATA[Test current teme]]></c_team>
<podium><![CDATA[Test podium]]></podium>
<points><![CDATA[Test points]]></points>
<g_p_entered><![CDATA[1950-05-12]]></g_p_entered>
<worldchanpionship><![CDATA[Test 12]]></worldchanpionship>
<h_race_f><![CDATA[Test hightest]]></h_race_f>
<h_g_points><![CDATA[Test hgp]]></h_g_points>
<pre_team><![CDATA[Test pre team]]></pre_team>
</driver>
```

now I want To save and read XML file which i got through webservice so that i can use my application without internet connection.

How to do this i have no idea?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can save the full xml file inside the cache folder of app and then read data from that xml file. So all time you read from data from that xml file and when internet connection available replace the xml file with new one.

Answer (score 0):

You can use GDataXMLNode library for it.Take a look at http://www.raywenderlich.com/725/how-to-read-and-write-xml-documents-with-gdataxml